# Python 3.5 virtualenv : pip3 installing tensorflow fails

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running Mac OS 10.5 (Yosemite) and I just setup a virtualenv with python 3.5 to play a little bit with tensorflow. The virtualenv is setup correctly. However, I cannot install tensorflow. I always get the following error messages:

```
(tensorflow) Tom@MBP:~/tensorflow$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

or this error:

```
(tensorflow) Tom@MBP:~/tensorflow$ pip3 install --upgrade \
>  https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
tensorflow-1.5.0-py2-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I actually do not understand what is happening here.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading `pip` to use latest version and see if it helps:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```